# Graphics3D model of the human body and organs?

Tags: graphics3d, anatomy

Does someone have a 3D model for a man (or woman) that can be displayed in *Mathematica* using `Graphics3D`? I have tried importing free .3DS models but they look pretty awful and you lose opacity, etc. Is there a complete model of a human  built from graphics primitives?

I've seen the [demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/3DSkeletalAnatomyOfTheTorso/) by Stewart Dickson but I need the whole body (and ideally some organs.)

Comment: Do you have link to "free .3DS models" you mentioned?

Comment: @Vitaly Kaurov I got them from http://www.cgtrader.com its free to sign up. It didn't make sense to pay and download one of the medical .3DS models so I downloaded and played around with a couple of the free models (for example the DNA model and Turntable model).

Answer (score 6):

## UPDATE (since version 10)

This now completely solved with built-in functionality, please read this blog for details: [**Visualizing Anatomy**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/03/10/visualizing-anatomy/). Below is a quote and example. You can also find a few videos at [Jeff Bryant on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/jeffbryant).

"In Mathematica 10, we introduced support for anatomical structures in EntityValue, which included, among many other things, a “Graphics3D” property that returns a 3D model of the anatomical structure in question. We also styled the models and aligned them with the concepts in the Unified Medical Language System (UMLS)."

[image]

```
AnatomyPlot3D[
  {{ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[{{-50, -146, 1500}, {-20, -146 - 20, 1550}, 
        {-50, -146 - 20, 1500}}], InfinitePlane[{{-50, -146, 1550}, 
        {-20, -146 - 20, 1550}, {-50, -146 - 20, 1550}}]}, 
    Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Skull"]}, Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Eye"], 
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Brain"], Directive[Specularity[White, 50], 
    Hue[0.58, 0, 1, 0.1], Lighting -> Join[{{"Ambient", Black}}, 
      Table[{"Directional", Hue[0.58, 0.5, 1], ImageScaled[{Sin[x], Cos[x], -0.5}]}, 
       {x, 0, 2*Pi - 2*(Pi/8), 2*(Pi/8)}]]], Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Nose"], 
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Neck"], Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "SkinOfHead"], 
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "SkinOfNeck"], Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Lip"], 
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Ear"]}, 
  PlotRange -> Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Head"], PlotRangePadding -> 10, 
  Background -> Hue[0.58, 1, 0.3], SphericalRegion -> True, ViewAngle -> Pi/5, 
  ImageSize -> 600, ViewPoint -> {-1.4, -1.29, 0.07}, ViewVertical -> {0.16, -0.08, 1.}]
```

---

## OLD answer

I doubt anyone would know where exactly is some full model, if there is any. But you can post-process imported model data to make them look better, apply color and opacity. For example from site you linked, I imported:

```
obj = Import["ZombieHunterHead_v3_87k.stl"]
```

[image]

Then I extract data and change rendering - add metallic color, add transparency, - now you can see his ear through his head:

```
Graphics3D[{GrayLevel[.25], Specularity[White, 10], EdgeForm[], 
  FaceForm[Opacity[.3]], Polygon[obj[[1, 2, 1]]]}, 
 Lighting -> Automatic, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: @Vitaly Kaurov In this case you use a stereolithography format .stl, is there a reason you didn't try a .3ds format? Both are based on triangulated representation of the surfaces.

Comment: @RWright no reason, - i just took first thing on that site. in your experience you cannot do the same thing with .3ds ?

Comment: @Vitaly Kaurov I downloaded a .3ds and its works the same way once you have figured out the `Part` specification. Thanks. I will try and fit a skin like `Texture` to the `Polygons` and will then post here. (PS Brett bear with me while I learn the syntax for posting here ;-)