# Finding a mapping between elements in two lists that satisfy some criterion (such as being less than threshold Euclidean distance apart)?

Tags: list-manipulation, geometry

I have two lists of $d$-dimensional coordinates, for example setting $d=3$ we might write:

```
L1 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{999,999,193}}
L2 = {{80,-10,-12},{1.1,2.4,3.1},{6.99,8.0435,8.999},{4,5.02,6.02}}
```

Here, some of the elements in $L_2$ are just the elements in $L_1$ perturbed in 3-space by some small amount (a MSD $\leq 0.5$), with the mapping $(1,2,3) \to (2,4,3)$ and where the coordinates at positions four in $L_1$ and one in $L_2$ do not having a mapping (i.e. there's not necessarily a bijection for the lists).

Is there a simple "one-liner" in Mathematica 9 that allows us to compare two lists and return a list of points that satisfy some mapping criterion, e.g. `EuclideanDistance` in the above example?

Update - For the above example, setting the `EuclideanDistance` to $R=1$ we'd specifically like to output:

{{{1,2,3},{1.1,2.4,3.1}},{{4,5,6},{4,5.02,6.02}},{{7,8,9},{6.99,8.0435,8.999}}}

(Elements can be in whatever order.)

Could we do this for a set of more than two lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will check that EuclideanDistance < 10 and show those pair of elements.

If you need every element of L1 with every element of L2 check:

```
dat = Select[Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, L1, L2, 1], 1], EuclideanDistance @@ # < 10 &]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {1.1, 2.4, 3.1}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5.02, 6.02}}, {{4, 5, 
>          6}, {1.1, 2.4, 3.1}}, {{4, 5, 6}, {6.99, 8.0435, 8.999}}, {{4, 5, 
>          6}, {4, 5.02, 6.02}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {6.99, 8.0435, 8.999}}, {{7, 8, 
>          9}, {4, 5.02, 6.02}}}

Verify:

```
EuclideanDistance @@@ dat
```

> {0.424264, 5.21927, 4.85592, 5.21507, 0.0282843, 0.0446458, 5.17308}

You can even visualize with a graph the pair relations:

```
Graph[L1~Join~L2, Rule @@@ flt, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

If you need corresponding pairs check:

```
Select[Transpose[{L1, L2}], EuclideanDistance @@ # < 10 &]
{{{4, 5, 6}, {1.1, 2.4, 3.1}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {6.99, 8.0435, 8.999}}}
```

Verify:

```
EuclideanDistance @@@ %
{4.85592, 0.0446458}
```

Comment: What? No ear sightings through the head? -1 then

Comment: @belisarius I don't quite understand?

Comment: @belisarius `Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPCmZmYGCw1tUEABDnAiw="]`

Comment: @FlavorOfLife He is joking (or is he?..). Cheerfully referring to [**this**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27727) ;-)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Hmm, why does it miss some of the mappings?  Specifically {1,2,3} --> {1.1,2.4,3.1}, and setting the EuclideanDistance to 0.5, it also misses {4, 5, 6} --> {4, 5.02, 6.02}?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Please let me know if my question was poorly written or confusing.

Comment: @FlavorOfLife updated.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Nice, thanks!

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Out of curiosity, what algorithm is Select using, and how does the computational cost scale with the size of the lists?

Comment: @FlavorOfLife thanks, I added a visualization too.

Answer (score 2):

These days, I would use `DistanceMatrix[]`:

```
L1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {999, 999, 193}};
L2 = {{80, -10, -12}, {1.1, 2.4, 3.1}, {6.99, 8.0435, 8.999}, {4, 5.02, 6.02}};

pos = Position[DistanceMatrix[L1, L2], x_ /; x < 1, {2}]
   {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 3}}

Transpose[MapThread[Part, {{L1, L2}, Transpose[pos]}]]
   {{{1, 2, 3}, {1.1, 2.4, 3.1}}, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 5.02, 6.02}},
    {{7, 8, 9}, {6.99, 8.0435, 8.999}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In versions 10.2+, you can use `RelationGraph`:

```
L1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {999, 999, 193}};
L2 = {{80, -10, -12}, {1.1, 2.4, 3.1}, {6.99, 8.0435, 8.999}, {4, 5.02, 6.02}};

rg1 = RelationGraph[EuclideanDistance @## < 1 &, L1, L2]
```

[image]

```
rg2 = RelationGraph[EuclideanDistance @## < 10 &, L1, L2]
```

[image]

```
oneliner = DeleteCases[Transpose[{VertexList @ #, 
 Function[x, AdjacencyList[#, x]]/@VertexList[#]}]&@RelationGraph[##], {_,{}}]&;

oneliner[EuclideanDistance @## < 1 &, L1, L2]// Grid[#, Dividers -> All]&
```

[image]

```
oneliner[EuclideanDistance @## < 10 &, L1, L2]// Grid[#, Dividers -> All]&
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but which method is more computationally efficient?

Comment: @Alexey,  I am afraid not this one:) Thank you for the vote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) approach to your question:

```
nf = Nearest[L1 -> "Index"];

Cases[
    SplitBy[Sort @ Thread[{nf[Join[L1, L2], {1, 1}], Join[L1, L2]}], First],
    x:{{{_Integer}, _}, __} :> x[[All,2]]
]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {1.1, 2.4, 3.1}}, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 5.02, 6.02}}, {{6.99, 8.0435, 
>      8.999}, {7, 8, 9}}}

You asked about a solution when there are more than 2 lists. In this case, another idea using [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) is to combine the lists, and then search for all elements within distance 1 of each member:

```
With[{all = Join[L1, L2]},
    clusters = DeleteDuplicates[
        Sort /@ Nearest[all -> "Index", all, {All, 1}]
    ];
    all[[#]]& /@ clusters
]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {1.1, 2.4, 3.1}}, {{4, 5, 6}, {4, 5.02, 6.02}}, {{7, 8, 
>      9}, {6.99, 8.0435, 8.999}}, {{999, 999, 193}}, {{80, -10, -12}}}

*(Note that I didn't bother pruning singleton clusters above)*.
The problem with the above approach is that clusters might need to be merged, reflecting the fact that the pairwise distance predicate is not transitive, i.e., $|p_1 - p_2| < 1$ and $|p_2 - p_3|<1$ does not imply that $|p_1-p_3|<1$. You will need to provide more information if merging is needed.

These approaches using [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) should be much faster than alternatives using [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer), [`RelationGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph) or [`DistanceMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix). For instance:

```
SeedRandom[68]
data = RandomReal[100, {10000, 3}];
clusters = DeleteDuplicates[Sort/@Nearest[data -> "Index", data, {All, 1}]];//AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.012938, Null}

I chose a particular [`SeedRandom`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom) and data range so that the clusters are all independent:

```
Length @ Flatten @ clusters
```

> 10000

For smaller data ranges, you will get clusters that aren't independent.